# Why is my Vue + Django Project still not allowing cors after proxy is setup?

Tags: django, vue.js, cors

I have a django + vue project

- Django `http://localhost:8000`
- Vue `http://localhost:8080`

I set the devserver proxy as mentioned by most people and documentation but I'm still getting the error

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:8000.
2024-01-02 12:03:14 See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    proxy: "http://localhost:8000",
  },
});
```

and my axios request is

```
axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/api")
      .then((response: any) => (this.players = response));
```

I can share my repo if this isn't enough information. I've got just a basic django and vue setup, mostly from boilerplate so I haven't added anything that should interfere with this. I'm just really confused on why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your django project you need to add library "django-cors-headers"

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

After that in your seetings.py you need to add new middleware

'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'

So you MIDDLEWARE list will look like below

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Right after MIDDLEWARE list you need to add new variable with list of valid cors addresses

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:8080'
]
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so fast! So I do have django cors headers already installed. I added ```CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS``` like mentioned above and restarted my servers but I am still getting this error.  Is there some other setting I am missing in django or vue?

Comment: I just mentioned that you are trying to proxy request via your vue app server, this is not cors error then. As an option you can try to send request directly to django app http://localhost:8000/...

Comment: Also in production deployment you will have something like nginx proxy server so I don't think that it's good idea to use nodejs proxy just to send requests to api server, or to mask the real api server address

Comment: Oh I see. By adding the vue proxy, I was causing the django allow cors to not work. Once I removed that it worked!! Thank you so much!!